# Eigenvalues of the symmetric normalized transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, markov-chains

I read this [paper](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Efan/wp/diameter.pdf) and I am confused about the range of eigenvalues of the symmetric normalized transition matrix. Specifically, I have a transition matrix $P = D^{-1}A$ of a strongly connected directed graph (or an irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain), where $D$ is the degree matrix, i.e., $D_{ii}$ is the outgoing degree of node $v_i$, $A$ is the adjacency matrix, and edges are unweighted.

Then this paper defines the normalized graph Laplacian of the directed graph based on the $P$ as:
$$\mathcal{L}=I-\frac{\Phi^{1 / 2} P \Phi^{-1 / 2}+\Phi^{-1 / 2} P^{\top} \Phi^{1 / 2}}{2}$$

where $\Phi$ is a diagonal matrix of a vector $\phi$, i.e., $\Phi_{ii} = \phi_i$. $\phi$ is the stationary distribution vector of $P$, i.e., $\phi$ is the eigenvector of eigenvalue 1 of $P$. And it is obvious that $\mathcal{L}$ is symmetric.

I have known that eigenvalues of $P$ are bounded in $(-1,1]$. This paper states that the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathcal{L}$ is 0 without proof.

Let:
$$T = \frac{\Phi^{1 / 2} P \Phi^{-1 / 2}+\Phi^{-1 / 2} P^{\top} \Phi^{1 / 2}}{2}$$

My question:

1. Why is the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathcal{L}$ is 0?
   (or why the largest eigenvalue of $T$ is also 1? )

I have known that $T$ has eigenvalue 1 corresponding to the eigenvector $\phi^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

2. What is the upper bound of eigenvalues of $\mathcal{L}$? (or is the upper bound existing?)

Comment: (1) is not very hard to check for yourself, $T\phi=?$

Comment: @user8675309 you are right, I have known that $T$ has an eigenvalue 1 with eigenvector $\phi^{\frac{1}{2}}$, but I do not know how to prove 1 is the largest eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: $\phi$ and hence $\phi^\frac{1}{2}$ is a positive vector and it follows from Perron-Frobenius theory that the associated eigenvalue is maximum modulus.

Comment: @user8675309 About the lower bound of $T$, I have known that the eigenvalues of $P$ are in (-1,1], do the lower bound of eigenvalues of $T$ is also the same with $P$?